# How to build a simple source code editor using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, text-editor

Hello there and Merry Christmas !!!

I am new to WPF and I am trying to build a text editor for a assembly language. The assembler provides me a two lists:

- a list of errors
- a list of warnings

My editor should have the ability to inport the contents of a file and display it in a text-panel. I want it to be similar to Visual Studio. Line numbers on the side. And a tabbed pane for the warning/error messages.

Each list element contains the line number as an Int and a String that contains the error/warning message. (It would be really cool if I could click on it in the tabbed pane and it would jump to that line and highlight it.)

How I said I am new to WPF, I don't know the control library and I don't have too much time to dig and get friendly with google.

So I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to at least the controls I need to develop my GUI.

My best regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I has for you is two links:

- [CodeyProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFdockinglib.aspx)
- [Commercial one (SandDock)](http://www.divelements.co.uk/net/controls/sanddockwpf/)

Answer (score 1):

Free one http://blog.bodurov.com/Wpf-Source-Code-Editor

Answer (score -1):

Our SyntaxEditor for WPF control was just released to the public last week.  It is a syntax-highlighting code editor control similar to the Visual Studio 2010 editor.  You can find more info about the control here:
www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/SyntaxEditor/